# Laravel 5 Apache 404, but fine on Heroku

Tags: apache, laravel, laravel-5, http-status-code-404

So title says it all. I have built an app that works fine on Heroku but surprising the routings are messed up on my local server. I have downloaded the WampServer and followed this guide for the set up http://www.terrymatula.com/development/2012/setting-up-a-virtual-host-for-wamp-and-laravel/.

didnt work though :(. Thoughts and suggestions?

Comment: but may I add that the root page can be visited just fine. all routes other than "/" are messed up

Comment: Did you check if mod_rewrite is enabled?

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks. Put up your answe so that i may tick it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if mod_rewrite is enabled?